# What is the Lucene query equivalent to a SQL `IS NULL OR someDate > GETDATE()`?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I have a bunch of documents with an optional `exiryDate` field and I need to get all non-expired documents. For documents with an expiryDate I can use `+expiryDate:[2020-08-03 TO *]` but how do I include the documents that don't have a value.

I'm using Lucene.Net 2.9.4.1.

For reference, and as I mentioned in the question title, I'm lookinf for the equivalent of this SQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM Documents
WHERE ( expiryDate IS NULL or expiryDate > @someDate)
```